# Finding difference between two commit points in GIT

Tags: git, bash, shell, github

Suppose I have a develop branch in GIT in which I made some commits.I know we can get the difference between two commits points.

git diff --name-only commit1 commit2.

Can anyone help me in writing the shell script which detect the changes automatically between the two commits points as soon as person check-in in develop branch or in any branch.

I want to achieve this in Continous Integration implementation using jenkins which will trigger the build as soon as person checkins the code in develop branch.

Comment: Jenkins can already poll a branch in a git repository regularily and trigger a build when the branch has changed.  Is this this the functionality you are looking for?  If the git project is hosted on github, Jenkins can register a webhook and be triggered immediately.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:-Thanks for the reply. I want to setup jenkins CI with bitbucket server as a repository.Jenkins should poll on any branch like master,develop or any feature branch.So wherever changes happen on any branch build should trigger. There are multiple codes in every branch,so jenkin should build only those code in which changes are done,so if there is anyway by which we can identify the changes between the last two commit points,please let me know .Once I got the list of files which got affected then I am ready with the build script. Let me know in case any more info needed.

Comment: Then github is not the right tag.